# _catalogs/masterpage/ returns 404 NOT FOUND - MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, 404

I am new in Sharepoint, but I am with a project that is using MOSS 2007.
When I try to access `Gallery > Master Page` it redirects to `http://myservername/_catalogs/masterpage/`.

The problem is that `http://myservername/_catalogs/masterpage/` is returning 404 code, page not found.
But if I create a site collection called "somesite" and access `http://myservername/sistes/somesite/_catalogs/masterpage/` is working fine.

I first thought it could be some problem with the master page, but if it was true it would return an error message instead of not finding the URL.

Comment: Do you have a site collection at the root?

Comment: I ran the commmand-line `stsadm -o enumallwebs`, it have shown two `site` tags, one has the `url` attribute starting with `/` and another starting with `/sites`. It means that there are 2 site collections, right ? 
PS: Sorry, I got the solution already built from another team that doesn't give us support anymore.

Comment: Yes, you have one at the root...